# Angular-UI-Calendar: Open popup on calendar dayClick

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, popover, angular-ui

I am using angular ui-calendar which has dayClick() function, which is working properly but when I am attaching popover code inside dayClick function, the popover is not opened.

I have got the solution for this, but it is working only with day/week not for agendaWeek or agendaDay

```
 $scope.onDayRender = function(date, cell) {
    console.log("### onDayRender");
    cell.popover({ content: "New Event: " + date });
};
```

Please give some solution for this to apply same for the agedaViews.

Comment: Can you provide the version of angular, bootstrap, and angular ui? There's a known issue with this particular problem with bootstrap 3 and angular ui.

Comment: Sure... I am using  AngularJS v1.0.1, Bootstrap v2.1.0 and angular-ui-FullCalendar v1.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

!!!Solution for AgendaViews!!!
Just add the select option in your calendar config array.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 500,
    editable: true,
    header:{
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay agendaWeek'
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent) {
        $scope.openPopover(start, end, allDay, jsEvent);
    }
  }
};

$scope.openPopover= function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent){
 $("#myPopover").popover('show');
}
```

Add a div with "myPopover" id in your HTML
like:

```
<div id="myPopover"></div>
```

Its working fine for me.... :-)

Comment: Note: in 1.6.4 you must declare 'selectable: true' in your config